# how to dynamically get an update excel radar chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

**Scenario**:
An excel form that saves some scores.

Each row represents a candidate. 
Each row has 8 topic cells with an integer score.

I can get a nice radar chart that shows each candidate with the scores. If I change the values the chart gets updated.
But if I add a new row submitting a new form, the chart doesn't get updated.

**Is there a way to get the chart updated when a new row is inserted?**
(I tried extending the range with empty rows but the chart shows me the empty rows)

Also, **is there any way to dynamically and temporarily remove a row (candidate) in the chart?** (imagine I have 100 candidates but I want to see only 4 in the chart, without removing the rows)

thanks

cirpo

Answer (score 1):

*I can suggest you few possible methods to dynamically update Chart, including Radar in Excel.*

**First is,** convert the `Source data range` into `TABLE`(Press `Ctrl+T`).

**Second is,** create `Dynamic Named Data range` using `OFFSET` function.

```
 =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,,,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,”<>”))
```

**Note,**

- After apply any of two methods, as soon 
  you insert a `NEW Record` or  modify 
  `Old One`, Excel will update the Chart.
- *To select desire rows in Chart you may 
  apply `FILTER` to `TABLE` or `DYNAMIC 
  RANGE`.*
- *Adjust Cell references & Sheet name in

  Formula as needed.*

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think it's already a table as when I select the rows the "table' tab appears (the excel gets created using an excel form).
I didn't understand where shall I create the "Dynamic Named Data range"
I'm using Excel for MacOS. thanks

Comment: @cirpo, **First edit the question and Add line at bottom that you are using MAC Os, and Add Tag also.** And if I'm not wrong `Offset` & `Countif` commands are also available in Excel on MAC  Os.

Comment: @cirpo,  select the Data Range which you have used/suppose to use to create Graph (in my Example is `A2:A100`), then **Go to Name Manger** then Click `New,` a dialog box will appear has New Name Title. Now at bottom find `Refers to` Text box in that enter the Formula I've shown in Answer. Don't forget  to adjust data range as your need.